# Filter dataframe with NA by a column condition in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame( Date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-24", "2017-02-24", "2017-02-25", "2017-02-25", "2017-02-25"),
                     var = c(2, NA, 1, 1,1, 7, 4))
```

I want to filter by date where var == 7

I tried with:

```
df %>% filter(Date[var  == 7])
```

But there is an error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `df$Date[df$var == 7]`

Comment: `df %>% filter(var  == 7)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583393/markus  thanks but I would like to hace complete row not just the columna df$Date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130044/lyzander. I would like to have all rows with the same date that ones which var= = 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` package

```
> df %>% filter(var == 7)

        Date  var
 1 2017-02-25   7
```

Comment: I would like to have all rows with that date. I think I´ve got it:  df %>% filter(Date %in% Date[var  == 7])